# SQL and escaped XML data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table with a mix of escaped and non-escaped XML. Of course, the data I need is escaped. For example, I have:

```
<Root>
    <InternalData>
         <Node>
              &lt;ArrayOfComment&gt;
                 &lt;Comment&gt
                    &lt;SequenceNo&gt;1&lt;/SequenceNo&gt;
                    &lt;IsDeleted&gt;false&lt;/IsDeleted&gt;
                    &lt;TakenByCode&gt;397&lt;/TakenByCode&gt;
                 &lt;/Comment&gt
              &lt;/ArrayOfComment&gt;
         </Node>
    </InternalData>
</Root>
```

As you can see, the data in the *Node* tag is all escaped. I can use a query to obtain the *Node* data, but how can I convert it to XML in SQL so that it can be parsed and broken up? I'm pretty new to using XML in SQL, and I can't seem to find any examples of this.

Thanks

Comment: You may consider using UDF and C# for parsing your XMLs and returning it as you like,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not given enough information about your end goal, but this will get you very close.  **FYI** - You had two missing ; both after `comment&gt`

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = '
<Root>
    <InternalData>
         <Node>
              &lt;ArrayOfComment&gt;
                 &lt;Comment&gt;
                    &lt;SequenceNo&gt;1&lt;/SequenceNo&gt;
                    &lt;IsDeleted&gt;false&lt;/IsDeleted&gt;
                    &lt;TakenByCode&gt;397&lt;/TakenByCode&gt;
                 &lt;/Comment&gt;
              &lt;/ArrayOfComment&gt;
         </Node>
    </InternalData>
</Root>
'

select convert(xml, n.c.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))
from @xml.nodes('Root/InternalData/Node/text()') n(c)
```

Output

```
<ArrayOfComment>
  <Comment>
    <SequenceNo>1</SequenceNo>
    <IsDeleted>false</IsDeleted>
    <TakenByCode>397</TakenByCode>
  </Comment>
</ArrayOfComment>
```

The result is an XML column that you can put into a variable or cross-apply into directly to get data from the XML fragment.

Comment: +1, this is slick.  This will only work with SQL 2005 or higher correct?

Comment: Cyberwiki - thanks! I'm hoping I get a chance to try this later today. I'll let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to look into a HTML Decoding UDF.  I did a quick search and found this one:

http://www.andreabertolotto.net/Articles/HTMLDecodeUDF.aspx

You may want to modify it so it only decodes `&gt;` and `&lt;`.  The one above seems to go above and beyond your needs.

**UPDATE**

@Cyberkiwi's solution seems to be a bit cleaner.  I will leave this up in case the version of SQL Server you are running doesn't support his solution.